# CSS how to only show 1 row and hide the others?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a nav at the top of my page. 
In it I have 5 market stocks for 5 different companies. I want to display the 5 at full width but as the window gets smaller, I basically want behavior which will cut off the ones that overflow, and resize the remaining ones to fill up the nav container (so let's say at some point it would only show 3 of the stocks and hide the others). Here is the code right now:

```
.stocks-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 150px);
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 75%;
  font-size: 11px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

What this does currently is almost what I need. The problem is that now the stock items that overflow, and should basically create a new row, get mushed on top of the first row. Again, I don't want them to create a new row, or be scrollable. I just don't want them to be showing at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Are all stocks in single row?

Comment: Thats what I want, yes.

Comment: Look at how the div's are getting cut off. That's not desirable. It needs to show as many as it can on a row (fully), and then basically ignore the rest (in the case of Grid, the rest form a new row, which i don't want to display)

Comment: @GeorgeMNajm you can use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; height: <height-of-each-stock-div>; overflow: hidden;`, there is no need to use grid

Comment: That just creates a new row, which wraps around. So now it has 2 rows displaying all the divs. It doesnt see it as overflow. That's why I think a grid is needed

Comment: See this, https://codepen.io/electriccode/pen/BVpRdw @GeorgeMNajm

Comment: Perfect, exactly the behavior I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the height of the items of your row is dynamic/unknown you can manipulate  the row heights in CSS like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72098443/473101

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS `max-height` and `@media` queries to achieve this effect:

- Give the `.stocks-container` a `max-height` which corresponds with the height of a single grid row and declare `overflow: hidden`

This ensures that there will now only ever be a single row visible (ie. no vertical wrapping of rows).

- Now add a short series of break-point media queries to reset `grid-template-columns` as percentages of the viewport width.

This enables those grid boxes which are still visible to fill the entire horizontal width reserved for the `.stocks-container`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.stocks-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, calc(20% - 6px));
grid-template-rows: 92px;
grid-column-gap: 6px;
grid-row-gap: 6px;
max-height: 92px;
font-size: 11px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.stocks-container div {
height: 80px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

    .stocks-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 6px));
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {

    .stocks-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(33.33% - 6px));
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .stocks-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, calc(50% - 6px));
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="stocks-container">

<div>
<h2>Company 1</h2>
<p>Company Stock</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Company 2</h2>
<p>Company Stock</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Company 3</h2>
<p>Company Stock</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Company 4</h2>
<p>Company Stock</p>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Company 5</h2>
<p>Company Stock</p>
</div>

</div>
```